# how to add letters/numbers values to single digit number in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

i am new to flutter, in learning phase.
in process of creating a simple flutter app which calculate the value of text/number entered in textformfield to single digit number by assigning A=1 to Z=26

Ex: if input is Hello then output should be 7
if input is hello 2 then output should be 9

i tried below code, but

1. it is not calculating to single digit,
2. it is not calculating for numbers,
3. when text box is empty and if i click calculate button, it is displaying old value which is calculated

```
class _ValueCalculatorState extends State<ValueCalculator> {
  final TextEditingController _inputText = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _resultsText = TextEditingController();

  String results = "0";
  String value = "";
  String inputText = "";

  void clearTextField() {
    _inputText.clear();
    _resultsText.clear();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _inputText,
                    minLines: 5,
                    maxLines: 9,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    onChanged: (name) {
                      inputText = name;
                      //value1 = name;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Text ',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 20.0,
                      horizontal: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    results,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 20.0,
                      horizontal: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
// calculation logic\
                      value = inputText.replaceAll(RegExp('[^A-Za-z0-9]'), '');
                      int sum = 0;
                      if (value.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
                          (value[i].toUpperCase() == value[i])
                              ? sum += (value.codeUnitAt(i) - 64)
                              : sum += (value.codeUnitAt(i) - 96);

                        setState(() {
                          results = sum.toString();
                        });
                      }
                      print(sum);
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 25,
                        horizontal: 60,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Text("Calculate"),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 20.0,
                      horizontal: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      clearTextField();
                      results = "0";
                    },
                    child: Text("Reset"),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 15,
                        horizontal: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you will find this helpful

```dart
class ValueCalculator extends StatefulWidget {
  const ValueCalculator({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ValueCalculatorState();
}

class _ValueCalculatorState extends State<ValueCalculator> {
  final TextEditingController _inputText = TextEditingController();

  final Map<int, int> map = {};

  String results = "0";
  String inputText = "";

  _ValueCalculatorState() {
    for (var i = 1, j = 'a'.codeUnits.first;
        j <= 'z'.codeUnits.first;
        i++, j++) {
      map[j] = i;
    }

    for (var i = 0, j = '0'.codeUnits.first;
        j <= '9'.codeUnits.first;
        i++, j++) {
      map[j] = i;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _inputText.addListener(_onInputTextChanged);
  }

  void _onInputTextChanged() => inputText = _inputText.text;

  void _clearTextField() {
    _inputText.clear();
    setState(() {});
  }

  int _calculate(String input) {
    int result = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < input.codeUnits.length; i++) {
      final key = input.codeUnitAt(i);
      final value = map[key];
      if (value != null) {
        result += value;
      }
    }

    while (result > 9) {
      int sumOfDigits = 0;
      for (int i = result; i > 0; i ~/= 10) {
        sumOfDigits += i.remainder(10);
      }

      result = sumOfDigits;
    }

    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _inputText,
                    minLines: 5,
                    maxLines: 9,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Enter Text ',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 20.0,
                      horizontal: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    results,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 20.0,
                      horizontal: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        results =
                            _calculate(inputText.toLowerCase()).toString();
                      });
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 25,
                        horizontal: 60,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Text("Calculate"),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 20.0,
                      horizontal: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      results = "0";
                      _clearTextField();
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 15,
                        horizontal: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Text("Reset"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _inputText.removeListener(_onInputTextChanged);
    _inputText.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a beautiful solution. However, there should be some explanation of the code and also, `map` should be updated to use the same values for both upper and lower case letters.

Comment: Thq Rahul, it solved my prob and also learned new thing.

Answer (score 0):

Update your onPressed() method of calculate button as below:
it will solve both issues, consider number and for empty string show 0

```
 onPressed: () {
// calculation logic
   value = inputText.replaceAll(RegExp('[^A-Za-z0-9]'), '');
   int sum = 0;
   if (value.trim().isNotEmpty) {
       for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (_isNumeric(value[i]) == true) {
                sum += int.parse(value[i]);
            } else {
              (value[i].toUpperCase() == value[i])
                     ? sum += (value.codeUnitAt(i) - 64)
                      : sum += (value.codeUnitAt(i) - 96);
           }
       }
    }
   setState(() {
      results = sum.toString() != "" ? sum.toString() : "0";
   });
}

//isNumeric func
 bool _isNumeric(String result) {
    return int.tryParse(result) != null;
  }
```

Comment: thq Modi, it resolved calculating for numbers but it still not calculating to single digit